# vim sort what is between pattern

Tags: mysql, database, sorting, logging, vim

Can you please show me how to sort each paragraph by the first number like this :

```
14  Time=110.07s (1541s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=0.1 (1), afadil[afadil]@economiste-www.avantis.pl
  SELECT t.word AS realword, i.word FROM search_total t LEFT JOIN search_index i ON t.word = i.word WHERE i.word IS NULL

10  Time=56.60s (566s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=14.6 (146), afadil[afadil]@economiste-www.avantis.pl
  SELECT n.nid FROM node n LEFT JOIN search_dataset d ON d.type = 'S' AND d.sid = n.nid WHERE d.sid IS NULL OR d.reindex <> N ORDER BY d.reindex ASC, n.nid ASC LIMIT N, N

1  Time=51.00s (51s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=0.0 (0), afadil[afadil]@economiste-www.avantis.pl
  SELECT SUM(i.score * t.count) AS score FROM search_index i INNER JOIN search_total t ON i.word = t.word INNER JOIN node n ON n.nid = i.sid  INNER JOIN search_dataset d ON i.sid = d.sid AND i.type = d.type WHERE n.status = N AND ( n.type NOT IN ('S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S') ) AND (i.word = 'S' OR i.word = 'S' OR i.word = 'S' OR i.word = 'S' OR i.word = 'S') AND i.type = 'S' AND (d.data LIKE 'S' AND d.data LIKE 'S' AND d.data LIKE 'S' AND d.data LIKE 'S' AND d.data LIKE 'S' AND d.data LIKE 'S' AND d.data LIKE 'S' AND d.data LIKE 'S' AND d.data LIKE 'S') GROUP BY i.type, i.sid HAVING COUNT(*) >= N ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT N, N
```

It is a mysql log so I want to sort it out, each line begins with a number.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each of your entries were a single line, this should do:

```
%sort! n
```

This sorts on the first `n`umber, and `!` reverses the sort order to descending.

As the format is three lines per data set, I'd first `:join` them together:

```
:%g/^\d/join 3
```

A join for dynamic (non-fixed line numbers) paragraphs would be

```
:%g/^\d/normal! V}J
```

(linewise visual mode, to next paragraph, `J`oin).

If you need to keep the separate lines, you can use `:substitute` (with `\r` replacement) to split them again after the sorting.

Comment: I pasted OP's data in my vim, the SQL statements `SELECT ...` are sitting in separated  lines...

Comment: I need the whole paragraph, it must stay as it is in order to get the full information, thanks anyway but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @AbdelilahBenaou: That wasn't clear from your question ("each line begins with a number"). I've extended my answer to deal with that.

Comment: @Ingo Karkat Thank you for your help, since it is a mySQL there are much more than three lines per data set sorry that I didn't mention that in my question.
Could you please update the answer.

Comment: @AbdelilahBenaou: That makes it more complicated, especially when the number of lines isn't fixed. See my edit.

Comment: @Ingo Karkat: Thank you very very much, it worked, sorry for my badly written post, I was in such hurry, thank you again.